How to get a user's goals details - progress and milestones - using Workday Web Services, simplest?
How can I get a the details for each of a worker's goals? I especially need goal progress and milestones.
Ideally Human_Resources/Get_Workers/Include_Goals would include progress and milestones. That does not seem to be an option.
The information I need seems to be only in the Talent/Get_Development_Items web interface, however I get Invalid instance ... Contextually_Secured for all variations of valid WID/Goal_Reference_IDs. Can I include Worker ID in the reference to unstick this? Is there a different interface? Am I missing something?
Human_Resources/Get_Workers/Include_Goals request:
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Workers_Request bsvc:version="v43.0">
            <bsvc:Request_References>
                <bsvc:Worker_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="Steve">
                    <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">afabf6fbbbbbbbbbbbb233d08</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
            </bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Response_Group>
               <bsvc:Include_Goals>1</bsvc:Include_Goals>
            </bsvc:Response_Group>
        </bsvc:Get_Workers_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>

and Human_Resources/Get_Workers/Include_Goals response:
<wd:Goal_Data>
    <wd:Goal_Reference_ID>GOAL-2-O-51312</wd:Goal_Reference_ID>
    <wd:Goal>A libero quis aspernatur</wd:Goal>
    <wd:Description>Created with care</wd:Description>
    <wd:Due_Date>2019-06-30</wd:Due_Date>
    <wd:Completion_Status_Reference>
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">ca3af9dsssssssssssssbb79</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Component_Completion_ID">INCOMPLETE</wd:ID>
    </wd:Completion_Status_Reference>
</wd:Goal_Data>

and my Talent/Get_Development_Items request with Goal_Reference_ID.
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Development_Items_Request bsvc:version="v43.0">
            <bsvc:Request_References>
                <bsvc:Development_Item_Reference>
                    <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Goal_Reference_ID">GOAL-2-O-51312</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Development_Item_Reference>
            </bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Response_Group>
                <bsvc:Include_Reference>1</bsvc:Include_Reference>
            </bsvc:Response_Group>
        </bsvc:Get_Development_Items_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>


Depending on how much information you are trying to get, you could create a Core Connector: Worker and add calculated fields to a Field Override Service and then call it in the Get_Workers API Call with the Field_And_Parameter_Criteria_Data section to call the Integration System ID of the CCW.
Unfortunately, it only returns text fields, so any multi-instance fields will need to be individually created as a CF, which can be a lot of calculated fields. The Field_And_Parameter_Criteria_Data  also won't work as a part of the change detection, just to note.

This seems more complicated than we had hoped. We don't have access to the configuration beyond permissioning, so we have to do everything through the Web Services interface. Is creating the CCW something that can be done through Web Services?

No, you'd create it in Workday.
